# Form validation with Jquery not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery to validate some fields in a form, and seem to be having an issue with one field in particular (`#inputTel`).

If an incorrect format is entered, an error message pops up underneath, which is fine, but the problem is once the correct format is entered the message does not disappear.

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/qBQad/)** with the complete demo.

This is the section in question:

```js
//Tel Validate
function is_valid_tel() {
    $this = $("#inputTel");
    var pattern = new RegExp("^\d{11}$");
    if (pattern.test($this.val())) { // valid
        if ($this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error")) $this.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
        $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "none");
        return true;
    } else { // error
        if (!$this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error")) $this.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
        $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "block");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Every other field works as expected except this one. My jQuery skills are limited so I'm unsure of how to solve this.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use the jQuery [Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the regex , when i put a 10 digit thing then also it goes to error part

Comment: its not the jquery , its your regex thats messing stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code:

Replace `var pattern = new RegExp("^\d{11}$");` with `var pattern = new RegExp(/^\d{11}$/);`

Updated code

```
//Tel Validate
function is_valid_tel() {
    $this = $("#inputTel");
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^\d{11}$/);// Update this line
    if (pattern.test($this.val())) { // valid
        if ($this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error")) $this.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
        $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "none");
        return true;
    } else { // error
        if (!$this.closest(".control-group").hasClass("error")) $this.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
        $this.siblings(".help-inline").css("display", "block");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rfg8H/

Comment: aswell as the amendment to the regexp itself I notice it has been taken out of its quotes, why did the "" need to be dropped?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like below, less cubersome:

```
$(function() {
            function validateTheForm() {
              var ok = true;
                $(".input-medium").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == "") //use regex actually here
                { 
                  $(this).next().css("display","inline");
                  ok = false;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).next().css("display","none");
                }


            });
                return ok;
            }
            $(".btn").click(function() {
              $("form").submit(validateTheForm());
              $("form").submit();

            });

        });
```